# A way to change how the header of a AMS-LaTeX file is presented?

Tags: formatting, header-footer

I'd like to change the way the header is presented in an AMS-LaTeX file... I based my file on [`testmath.tex`](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/amslatex/math/testmath.tex).

First, I'd like to allow my header, or represented by `\markboth`, to show up in the first page.

Second, instead of showing REFERENCE in the header of the pages where reference is listed, I'd like to make my file present the header as in other pages.

How can I do this?

Comment: the file `testmath.tex` uses `\documentclass{article}` which has no inherent connection to `amsmath`, and thus not to ams-latex.  `amsmath` is an add-on package that has no effect on page headers. so this question applies to any use of the basic latex `article` class.

Answer (score 7):

1. Say, instead of the simple `\maketitle`,

   ```
   \maketitle\thispagestyle{headings}
   ```

   This will override the choice of page style `empty` made by the command.
2. Put in the preamble

   ```
   \makeatletter
   \renewcommand{\@mkboth}[2]{}
   \makeatother
   ```

   This will neutralize the `\markboth` command issued by `thebibliography` (via `\@mkboth` which is usually equivalent to `\markboth`).